# Visual Studio 2012: tcl8.6.0 dosen't compile in VC11 (via makefile.vc)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tcl

tcl8.6.0 doesn't compile in VS11 with the makefile.vc provided by tcl.

I just had to deinstall VS11 and reinstall VC10 (visual studio 2010).

The README file in the "win" folder notes that Visual Studio 6.0 or newer should work, 
but it seems the readme file is not up to date.

It seems that MS breaks the needed functionality with every release.
For python the situation seems to be the same:
http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-July/121122.html

Any solution without the makefile doesn't make sense, as the tcl extensions wouldn't compile.

Can someone confirm that it is impossible to compile tcl8.6 with VS11? (using the provided makefile.vc?)

--
(I would strongly advice against using VC11 at the moment, it's just a huge waste of time.)

Comment: I vaguely remember some discussion of building with MSVC (I forget the version) late in the cycle, but I use OSX so I can't check. I also didn't use MSVC even way back when I was building on Windows…

Comment: I am forced to use MSVC as I am porting something to MSVC. Unfortunately, a lot of tcl users use MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what problems you have compiling, as you did not mention it.

But just using:

```
cd win
nmake -f makefile.vc
```

just worked for me, in the usual VC 2012 (Express for Desktop) command prompt on Windows 8 Pro.

The tests mostly run, just some link, http and timing relevant tests fail.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. as I get different results! could you specify perhaps: you are on a 64bit system? What is the exact tile of the VC 2012 command prompt? (I had at least two different VC 2012 command prompts) What is the download link of VC 2012? What is the download link of tcl? (for the latter I used "tcl860-src.zip" from http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html)

Comment: Sure: Win8 Pro 64-Bit, Windows SDK installed plus the Visual Studio Express from (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/deu/downloads#d-express-windows-desktop) updated to SP1. Same Tcl sources you used. I used the normal link to the command prompt that gets placed in the (non existant on win8, so it ends up in the start window) start menu on windows.